# Iterate over files in a subfolder

Tags: bash, loops, path

new here, learning bash for first time.
I'm trying to iterate over files named "list.txt" placed in subfolders, manipulate and create a new files, under the same subfolder. The nest could be like this:
`inventory/product_names1/list.txt`
`inventory/product_names2/list.txt`
As `product_names` is completly random, I would like to iterate over all list.txt files with unix cms like sed/grep/cut and create a new file, under the same random `product_names` folders.

> for f in $( find . -name 'list.txt'); do for list in $f; do cat $f | cut -d']' -f2- > "$f/new_file.txt" ; done ; done

I can access files into the nest using find command. How can I redirect output in the right subfolder if the `product_names` is random?

`inventory/product_names1/list.txt`
`inventory/product_names1/new_file.txt`
`inventory/product_names2/list.txt`
`inventory/product_names2/new_file.txt`

This script is intended to work in the root folder, pointing and working with entime path "inventory". $f access to `inventory/product_names1/list.txt` but I need the output in `inventory/product_names1`. How can I redirect correctly if I don't have the right value/variable?

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find common errors in shell code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use parameter expansion to remove the file name from the path, or you can iterate over all the directories and only work on them if they contain the `list.txt` file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for list in inventory/*/list.txt ; do
    new=${list%/*}/new_list.txt
    echo "$list" "$new"
done

# OR

for dir in inventory/* ; do
    if [[ -f $dir/list.txt ]] ; then
        echo "$dir"/list.txt "$dir"/new_list.txt
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` can not only find files but also execute commands when a file is found:

```
find . -type f -name 'list.txt' -execdir sh -c 'cut -d"]" -f2 list.txt > new_file.txt' \;
```

Explanations:

- `-type f` condition added to skip directories named `list.txt`. If some of your `list.txt` files can be symbolic links and you want to consider them too, use `-type f,l` with GNU `find`. With other `find` you may need to use `\(-type f -o -type l\)`.
- `-execdir` runs the command in the directory where the file was found.
- By default `find` does not print when `-execdir` is used. If you need it add the `-print` command:

  ```
  find . -type f -name 'list.txt' -execdir sh -c 'cut -d"]" -f2 list.txt > new_file.txt' \; -print
  ```